# Problem creating my own custom tags(JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, custom-controls

I am learning to create my own custom tags, but i am having a bit of trouble, i cant make this simple app use the tag i created. I think i did everything fine, but i am afraid the paths to the new library i created is wrong. Maybe someone can help me find where my error is and understand the reason of it. This is what i did so far:

**1- I created the tag as an xhtml chunk(mybutton.xhtml)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition>
    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="#{buttonSubmitLabel}" />
    <h:commandButton type="reset" value="#{buttonResetLabel}" />
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

**2- Then i created an .xml file that will act as the libraries where all my custom tags are indexed(mytagsconfig.taglib.xml)**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://mytags.com/facelets</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>mybutton</tag-name>
        <source>mytags/mybutton.xhtml</source>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

**3- I tried to register my new library in the web.xml, so i can use it**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>CHAPTER 5 Creating your own Custom tags</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- REGISTERING A CUSTOM TAG INTO JSF APPLICATION -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mytagsconfig.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

**4- And last i try to use the tag in some page(In my case inside a component that is inserted in a template)**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:mytags="http://mytags.com/facelets">

<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/templates/masterLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="pagetitle">
    Defining custom tags
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
    Defining custom tags is a 3 step process:
    <ul>
        <li>Use ui:compisition to create some content.(Custom tags are stored in WEB-INF/customtags)</li>
        <li>Declares the custom tag in a tag library descriptor into the WEB-INF folder(Example: mycustomtags.taglib.xml).</li>
        <li>Register the tag library descriptor in the web.xml.</li>        
    </ul>

    <!-- Here should go a call to the new created tag -->
    <mytags:mybutton buttonSubmitLabel="Submit" buttonResetLabel="Reset" /> 

    </ui:define>    
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

****Update****
When i build i see the index.xhtml page, but the custom tag is not there(I dont see the 2 buttons)

Comment: @BalusC I run the program and at the browser i see 404 error, and the console says: `WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /WEB-INF/templates/masterLayout.xhtml @33,66 <ui:include src="WEB-INF/templates/defaultContent.xhtml"> Invalid path : WEB-INF/templates/defaultContent.xhtml` It is like if something is wrong with the template, but don,t know what. I will paste the template i use above.

Comment: FYI: the above error is just a result of dirty workspace/project/deploy. OP mentioned in a comment of a deleted answer of mine that it was gone after cleaning/rebuilding it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your taglib declaration in `web.xml` does not point the right filename.

You said that you've created a `/WEB-INF/mytagsconfig.taglib.xml`, but you've declared it in `web.xml` as `/WEB-INF/mytags.taglib.xml` instead. Fix it accordingly.

Not directly related to the problem, but consider upgrading to JSF/Facelets 2.0 compatible taglib root declaration and `web.xml` context param name.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- Taglib config here. -->
</facelet-taglib>
```

and

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mytagsconfig.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I upgraded to facelets2.0 as you recommended, and changed the paramname from `faces.LIBRARIES` to `faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES` Now i see my new custom tag in the browser. Everithing works fine. Nice now i know how to create my own tags :) Thanks BalusC

Comment: You're welcome. You may find this related question/answer useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-component

Comment: Cool, that is a really useful one :)